# Ending a flash movie with an animated GIF

Tags: flash

Is there anyway to end a Flash movie with an animated GIF that keeps animating indefinitely in the window of the flash player?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a class created that can load and play most animated GIFs.

> With this new `GIFPlayer` class, everything is handled, I have added some methods as you would call on a traditional `flash.display.MovieClip`
>   Source: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95